# Are extern extern "C", and extern "C" extern, allowed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, extern, extern-c

Is this code correct?

```
extern "C" extern int x;       // 1
extern extern "C" int y;       // 2
extern "C" extern "C" int z;   // 3

int main() { }
```

gcc rejects 1 and 2 as syntax errors and accepts 3.  clang accepts all three but gives a duplicate-declaration-specifier warning about them all.

Maybe relevant is C++17 [dcl.stc]/5:

> The `extern` specifier can be applied only to the names of variables and functions. The `extern` specifier cannot be used in the declaration of class members or function parameters. For the linkage of a name declared
>   with an `extern` specifier, see 6.5. [Note: The `extern` keyword can also be used in *explicit-instantiation*s and *linkage-specification*s, but **it is not a *storage-class-specifier* in such contexts.** —end note ]

Comment: Why do you feel you want to write code like this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How is that relevant?

Comment: \*Sigh\* Alright, never mind.

Comment: This is one of those questions where I'm sure I'm about to learn something worth learning, but I'm not quite sure what. The only note I can find relevant to it is that before wrapping a non-system header `#include` in `extern "C"`, you should verify that the header does not already contain a linkage specification -- implying that doing it twice would be unwanted.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah this came up when I was looking at some code using funky macro hackery

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://youtu.be/tsG95Y-C14k?t=70) video?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`extern extern "C"` is not valid syntax, as `extern "C"` is not a specifier and thus cannot occur in a *decl-specifier-seq*. Instead `extern "C"` can only appear as part of a *linkage-specification*, for which the syntax is

> `extern` *string-literal* `{` *declaration-seq*(opt) `}`
>   `extern` *string-literal* *declaration*

Thus, `extern "C"` must occur first.

Also, `extern "C" extern` is not valid either, according to [dcl.link]/7:

> A declaration directly contained in a *linkage-specification* is treated as if it contains the `extern` specifier (10.1.1) for the purpose of determining the linkage of the declared name and whether it is a definition. Such a declaration shall not specify a storage class.

(`extern` is a storage class specifier.)

It doesn't seem that there is any rule forbidding `extern "C" extern "C"`, though.